# jQuery selector for target event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following **CSS** and **HTML**:

```css
a {
  padding: 20px;
}
div {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 600px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#target_id_1">link 1</a>
<a href="#target_id_2">link 2</a>
<a href="#target_id_3">link 3</a>
<a href="#target_id_4">link 4</a>
<a href="#target_id_5">link 5</a>
<div id="target_id_1" class="target_class">I'm the target 1!</div>
<div id="target_id_2" class="target_class">I'm the target 2!</div>
<div id="target_id_3" class="target_class">I'm the target 3!</div>
<div id="target_id_4" class="target_class">I'm the target 4!</div>
<div id="target_id_5" class="target_class">I'm the target 5!</div>
```

I want to perform certain jquery operations when `div`s with class *"target_class"* are targeted.

I know this can be achieved by adding a common class to these `a` tags (say, *"link"*) and then binding a click event handler with that class like this:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    //code
});
```

What I needed to know was: ***Is there a jQuery handler for target event for a particular class/id?***

Something like:

```
$(".target_class").target(function(){
   //code
});
```

If not, are there any ***alternatives*** to achieve this?

Comment: No, it's just a link.

Comment: Aren't there any alternatives? Otherwise, I must add a class to all the anchor tags!

Comment: No, there are alternatives.  Wait for my answer :)

Comment: I do not understand your question at all.... Could you clarify?

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by *"`target_class` are targeted"*?

Comment: I needed to know if there was a jquery selector for a particular class/id being "targeted" (by an anchor tag).

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon when you click a page anchor, the browser scrolls to the element which has that ID. That's the "targeting" action here. OP is asking if there is a listenable event for "focusing" that element.

Comment: "targeted" in the sense that when I click the anchor tag div's with classes "target_class" are being targeted.

Comment: Seems to me you can just get the href attribute from the `a` tag and use it as a selector

Comment: @theScorpion so is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ngoc8jzk/

Comment: @Godisgood Your answer works if I name the id's in that fashion, will it work for classes?

Comment: @Karl Yes, something like that. I wanted to know if this was possible by attaching *some* event handlers to `div`s with classes 'target_class'

Comment: @theScorpion built in, no. But you can easily create it with the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this works is the selector (`a[href^="#target"]`) matches every `<a>` tag whose `href` begins with `#target`.

```js
$('a[href^="#target"').click(function(){ alert('You targeted something.'); });
```

```css
a {
  padding: 20px;
}
div {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 600px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#target_id_1">link 1</a>
<a href="#target_id_2">link 2</a>
<a href="#target_id_3">link 3</a>
<a href="#target_id_4">link 4</a>
<a href="#target_id_5">link 5</a>
<div id="target_id_1" class="target_class">I'm the target 1!</div>
<div id="target_id_2" class="target_class">I'm the target 2!</div>
<div id="target_id_3" class="target_class">I'm the target 3!</div>
<div id="target_id_4" class="target_class">I'm the target 4!</div>
<div id="target_id_5" class="target_class">I'm the target 5!</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted. This works perfectly, but what about the class part?

Comment: You won't need the class part if you use this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this event does not exist in js, but you can handle hash change :

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
   if ( $(this.location.hash).hasClass('target_class') ){
      // do stuff
   }
});
```